# one file sound?

Tags: android, class, audio

I am making an application for the android platform, its a 2d game. I have some sounds for example, coins, hit, shooting, reload etc. I have them all in one file named sounds. My question is, can i use this one file or do i need to separate it to many separate files? is there any way using the time that each one of them starts and stops?

for example, one starts at 0:15 and stops at 0:17. can I cut the sound using eclipse in my activity  or create a new one that i can import the sounds from them, which will handle all of the sounds?

(What i mean is a class named 'Sound' for example, and each time i need a to use a sound, lets say 'coins', i could just write 'Sound.coins.play').

By The Way, I am using canvas on a surface view and i control it in a thread using lockcanvas and unlockandpost.

Answer (score 0):

The `SoundPool` class is what they typically use for game sounds. It supports loading several logically distinct sounds from the same file.

Comment: can you include an example or tutorial for how to use it?